# Crashlytics - can't add custom keys, they are not caught on crash

Tags: swift, crashlytics

I have a problem with crashlitycs for iOS - I cant set custom keys (they are not registered online).
Everything else is working, I can record the same data in customlogs - that works perfectly, but custom keys doesn't show whatsoever.
Part of the code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    setCrashlitycsKeys()
}

internal func setCrashlitycsKeys() {
    if let userId: Int64 = UserDefaultsHelper.get(for: .UserId) {
        Logger.shared.log.warning("User Id: \(userId)")
        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier(String(describing: userId))
        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setObjectValue(userId, forKey: "userId")
    }

    if let jsonString: String = UserDefaultsHelper.get(for: .InstanceModuleConfigJson) {
        let instancesModuleConfigModel = InstancesModuleConfigModel(JSONString: jsonString)
        if let instance = instancesModuleConfigModel?.id {
            Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setObjectValue(instance, forKey: "instanceId")
            Logger.shared.log.warning("Instance Id: \(instance)")
        }
    }
}
```

Logger is just a custom CLSLogv and it works perfectly -
[screenshot for log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltS16.png)
 while theres nothing in keys
[screenshot no keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4X2s.png)
(it says that no keys found)

Any ideas what can I do or check to make this working? I've spend several hours trying different types of keys, different places and so on but nothings working.

I Use Xdode Version 11.2.1 (11B53),
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found a bug after few hours of searching, in my project I have few targets (mainApp, AppCommon etc) - project is big, so I import smaller functionalities.  I had to use Crashlytics pod in 2 of them and that caused an error